# Does anyone tell me what is the wrong with this code

Tags: javascript

```
function ge(id){
    this.id=id;
    this.d=document;
    this.w=window;
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
ge.prototype={
    set_in:function(value){
        this.innerHTML=value;
    },
    getIn:function(){
        return document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML;
    },
    foc:function(){
        document.getElementById(this.id).focus();
    }
}
```

i want to do is that if i call ge('id').getIn() will result in innerHTML of that element

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: this Error : Cannot call method 'getIn' of null

Comment: why not setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: @BhavikPatel - its because you have not instantiated the ge object. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `new ge("header").getIn();` instead of just `ge("header").getIn();` - Or create another function that returns a new instance of `ge` - For ex:

```
function newge(id) {
    return new ge(id);
}
function ge(id){
    this.id=id;
    this.d=document;
    this.w=window;
    return this; //document.getElementById(id);
}
ge.prototype={
    set_in:function(value){
        this.innerHTML=value;
    },
    getIn:function(){
        return document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML;
    },
    foc:function(){
        document.getElementById(this.id).focus();
    }
}
newge("header").getIn();
```

Comment: as long as he returns an object from within the constructor, this can never work.

Comment: this absolutely does. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RRu89/ - you totally cannot call a method without first instantiating the object - and that was the issue with the code in question.

Comment: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @techfoobar: kidding? you modified the code. This would be his code: http://jsfiddle.net/RRu89/1/. All he needs to do is to ommit the `return` statement. No need to return `this` even. Then he can just call `new ge('id');`

Comment: No. My initial answer had the return stmt commented (obviously needed) if you had noticed closely. Also, see no edits in my answer till now.

Comment: @BhavikPatel - Are you getting that in the fiddle i posted? !

Comment: @jAndy - exactly. the missing 'new' was the issue as i pointed out. Not just the return statement.

Comment: @techfoobar: even when he calls the constructor with `new` it can't work as long as the OP returns any custom object, like he does.

Comment: @techfoobar this is working in fiddle but not in my code

Comment: @BhavikPatel - Is there an online link where i can see it?

Comment: hey it's working but now do me one more favor if you can help me out

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a `DOM Node` in that constructor function. I guess you use it as a constructor, so you overwrite the `Object` which it actually should return.

Just skip the

```
return document.getElementById(id);
```

and you're good. You can store that node reference in some `this.myRef` value instead.

---

After you removed that `return` statement, you need to create an instance. Like

```
var myGE = new ge('id');
```

and then you can finally call

```
myGE.getin();
```

Comment: i did this but it still not working

Comment: but i dnt want to create object everytime

Comment: you'll have to create the object. you will not be able to call the functions inside ge without instantiating it first. maybe you can hide the instantiation inside another function at best.